# NativeScript java.lang.RuntimeException error

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm new to NativeScript. Trying to create an android app using NativeScript, Angular2 & TypeScript.

Followed the instruction given at here http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1 . But, just in initial step only got Stuck. Can't able to see the Hello World page itself.

Here is my error log report -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "./", relative to: /
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4710)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "./", relative to: /
    at com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:220)
    at com.tns.Module.bootstrapApp(Module.java:252)
    at com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:234)
    at com.tns.RuntimeHelper.initRuntime(RuntimeHelper.java:129)
    at com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:15)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
    ... 8 more
```

Any idea, what's I'm doing wrong ?

Regards

Comment: Hi mi6crazyheart - Please specify after which command you are encountering this error as it is a bit unclear what do you mean by initial step.. I suspect you are runnig "tns run" but on which platform and with which version of NativeScript!? I would suggest to update your NativeScript to the latest vbersion 2.0.0 (npm install -g nativescript)

Comment: Commands which I ran was - ```tns create bhramaan --ng,
cd bhramaan,
tns platform add android,
tns run android```

Comment: I talked ablout this thing in NativeScript Slack channel. I think there is some issue in ```tns create bhramaan --ng``` command. I build one more project without using```--ng ``` , it's worked fine.

Comment: I just followed the exact steps and the project was build with success. The support for angular-2 has come with version 2.0 of  {N} so can you check your current version with tns --version

Comment: My NativeScript CLI version also : 2.0.0